# Error using if else statement nested in case_when

Tags: r

I noted a bug using if else statement nested in case_when:

```
tipo="p"
n=2
case_when(
  tipo=="p"~if(n>0){3}else{4},
  tipo=="d"~if(n>0){c(3,1)}else{c(4,1)},
  tipo=="r"~3
)
```

This returns

```
> case_when(
+   tipo=="p"~if(n>0){3}else{4},
+   tipo=="d"~if(n>0){c(3,1)}else{c(4,1)},
+   tipo=="r"~3
+ )
[1] 3 3
```

Instead of `3`, what were my intention. What am I doing wrong?

I would thank any help.

Comment: it's debatable if this is a bug in the sense of, if you look at the source code for `case_when()`, it's `vec_recycle_common()` which is recycling the values, and presumably they added that line of code on purpose. But what reason is unclear to me rn

Comment: This is the intended behavior of `case_when`. Note that the documentation says "All inputs will be recycled to their common size.", and while it may be surprising that the function is looking inside all your if-else expression to glean the size of the output, that's how the function is intended to work. If you're trying to implement a sequence of conditional logic where the the output may be of different *shapes*, `case_when` probably isn't the right tool. Try either `switch` or simply a direct series of `if`/`else` statements.